# 192.168.2.xy can't access 192.168.1.xy (: 255.255.255.0)

Tags: router, subnet

My goal is to access my NAS from a PC, but NAS is not reachable.

**Situation**

Here is my network configuration:

```
Router 1: 192.168.2.1 : 255.255.255.0

Router 2: 192.168.1.1 : 255.255.255.0

NAS: 192.168.1.108 (in Network of Router 2)

PC Foo: 192.168.2.xy
```

**Problem**

So problem is that I can't get access from "PC Foo" (no Ping possible) to my NAS. All other PCs with IP 192.168.**2**.xy get access.

**Questions**

I'm not sure but is this a subneting-problem?

What can I do to get access, when I don't want to change the IPs?

Comment: So all your devices can communicate across both networks except the NAS? Do you have the correct default gateway set on the NAS?

Comment: @jlehtinen: "communicate across": I haven't try this, but I suppose no.

Comment: How are the two networks physically connected?

Comment: @Zoredache: Router 2 is connected to Router 1 via LAN-cabel. PC Foo is connected via WLAN to Router 1. NAS via switch with oder PC to Router 2.

Comment: 1) Arg. Confuzling post with LAN1 in 192.168.2 and LAN1 in 192.168.1.0/24. That really threw me in a loop. 2) Useful background reading: [this post on our sister site](http://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-ipv4-subnetting-work).  3) All other PCs... where are these other PCs connected to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set static routes in each router for the other router's network and make sure packet forwarding is enabled.

Comment: Thanks for answer (+1 for that). That is what I supposed. Problem is I can't find how to set this in Router 1. It is very stupid router provides by my provider. Are there any synonyms for "static routes"?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you have router 2 doing NAT when it doesn't need to be. Disable NAT and DHCP service in router 2, to make it just act like an Ethernet switch/bridge. Then your whole network will be all one subnet, which is probably a better setup for you anyway.

If you have a good reason for router 2 to be doing NAT, then you'll need to enter NAT port mappings into it so anything on router 1's network can get to things they need to get to on router 2's network. You'll also need to set a static route on router 1 so it knows to send all 192.168.1.x traffic to router 2, or you'll need to set that kind of static route on all machines on router 1's network.

Comment: Thanks for answer (+1 for that). I will try this. Dividing the subnets has more are "organizational" reasons, but if can't setup the static route I will consider to create "one subnet".